# I want to start getting into Yu-Gi-Oh! where should I start?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

If I was to start watching all the series of Yu-Gi-Oh! (the orginal one), what should I start with first?

The books or the movies? And can you please list them in order too?

Comment: Related:http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11248/whats-the-correct-order-in-which-to-watch-the-yu-gi-oh-seasons-episodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start watching the series you should better start from the first anime adaptation of the manga with the same name released in 1998.

see [Yu-Gi-Oh! (1998 TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_(1998_TV_series))
It is based on chapters 1-59 of the Yu-Gi-Oh! manga series. here is a list of the first 59 [episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Yu-Gi-Oh!_(1998)_episodes) in the anime.

You should check this post. [What's the correct order in which to watch the Yu-Gi-Oh! seasons/episodes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11248/whats-the-correct-order-in-which-to-watch-the-yu-gi-oh-seasons-episodes)

For the Movies here is [5 titles](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Movies). source: yugioh.wikia.com

Honestly I am a fan of the Anime and its [Card-game gameplay](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/). I even attended Conventions here in our country where dual matches were held and participated by trading card enthusiasts.

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is a fairly opinion-based question, since some people will say the anime is superior to the manga, while many others will say vice versa. I would say the manga is a better place to start; it is its most faithful form, without fillers and without card games shoehorned into every available opportunity.

It should be noted that unlike the anime, the manga takes a while before focusing on card games. Also, in terms of the anime, there are two separate ones, the first made by Toei and the second made by Studio Gallop, though the second continues where the first lefts off. These follow the plot of the manga (although the Toei one is fairly loose about it.) though with noticeable differences (e.g. fillers).

As for the movies, the first one, simply titled "Yu-Gi-Oh!" Is based on the Toei adaptation. The Pyramid of Light movie is only possibly canon to the Gallop anime, and even then ambiguously so. It takes place shortly after the Battle City arc. "Bonds between time" is sort of commemorative, and it crosses over with GX and 5Ds; I do not recommend watching it before watching GX and 5Ds.

As for the manga, there is also a short series called "Yu-Gi-Oh! R" which also takes place after the Battle City arc, and is also disputed in its canonicity.

The other works, such as GX, 5Ds, Zexal and Arc-V, are, unlike the original, Anime first before manga, instead of the other way around. These certainly does not encompass the "original one" as you mentioned in your question.